# JavaScript code for converting html output to be displayed as table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on chatbot project.

I want to display the records fetched from database in the form of tables in the UI.

I have written the following code:

```
table="<table><tbody>"
  for i in answer_list:
      table+="<tr>"
      for j in i:
          table+="<td>"+str(j)+"</td>"
      table+="</tr>"

  table+="</tbody></table>"   
  print(table)

  return answer_list
```

The answer list here contains the output as:

```
<table><tbody><tr><td>aani</td></tr><tr><td>shawn</td></tr><tr><td>sharu</td></tr><tr><td>bin</td></tr><tr><td>pradi</td></tr><tr><td>vaiz</td></tr><tr><td>bhat</td></tr><tr><td>kim</td></tr><tr><td>wini</td></tr><tr><td>uma</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

(with html tags like table, td, tr)

I want this as table in the UI, so what is the code to be written in JavaScript to do this (convert it into tables)?

Answer (score 0):

```
tableBody="<tbody>"
   for i in answer_list:
   tableBody+="<tr>"
   for j in i:
      tableBody+="<td>"+str(j)+"</td>"
   tableBody+="</tr>"

tableBody+="</tbody>"   
print(tableBody)

return answer_list
```

if you use Jquery do this print method

```
function print(table){
    $("#tableId").html(table);
}
```

Or If you use pure javascript do this method

```
function print(table){
    document.getElementById("tableId").innerHTML = table;
}
```

Comment: hey shady thanks for the reply, forgot to mention a few things the code above it written in python framework where it retrieves data from SQL but this not the only mode of replies  so the table generation has to dynamic if a list is received

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like below.

```js
document.write('<table><tbody><tr><td>aani</td></tr><tr><td>shawn</td></tr><tr><td>sharu</td></tr><tr><td>bin</td></tr><tr><td>pradi</td></tr><tr><td>vaiz</td></tr><tr><td>bhat</td></tr><tr><td>kim</td></tr><tr><td>wini</td></tr><tr><td>uma</td></tr></tbody></table>');
```

Instead of your `print(table)`, use `document.write(table);`

Comment: but its not written in html

Comment: get name error as NameError: global name 'document' is not defined